# jQuery traversing vs pseudo classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the difference between traversing and pseudo classes in jQuery selectors.

In a DOM that contains the following:

```
<ul id="destination">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

The following jQuery codes will select the same elements:

```
# Pseudo class
$("#destination li:first");

# Traversing
$("#destination").find("li").first();
```

I heard that the second way is more efficient, in spite of taking more keystroks. What is the best practice?

Comment: The performance difference is trivial for most applications. Use whichever you think looks prettier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css selectors vs jquery traversal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308405/css-selectors-vs-jquery-traversal)

Comment: the performance is marginal, is just the time it takes about the parsing of the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can measure efficiency via your F12 Developer Tools. For instance, here's the output from the [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255005(v=vs.85).aspx) in Internet Explorer on both of these approaches using jQuery 2.1.2-pre.

Following is the result of using `$.fn.find` and `$.fn.first`. You'll note that it is considerably less work than using pseudo-classes.

[image: Traversal]

As noted above, using pseudo-classes (non-standard [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) syntactic-sugar) requires a bit more work:

[image: Pseudo Classes]

The results speak for themselves. Although these results are distinctly different, don't let this sway you one way or another. Use what is appropriate for your project. The actual performance differences would be negligible, and not likely worth your concern.

Comment: How do you do such a test? I can type my commands in the console of the dev tool on my browser, but I would like to know where I can get those details shown in the picture.

Comment: @MikeC You can find more information on Internet Explorer's Profiler tool online here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255005(v=vs.85).aspx. Once you have profiled your application, you'll want to view the *Call Tree* rather than the enumerated function list.