# What is the difference between a multi-part jQuery selector like $('.element .childElement') and $('.element').find('.childElement')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I might be confused but it seems like sometimes one of these two ways works when the other one fails.

Let's say the html is like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="nestedDeep">
        <div class="clickMe">ClickMe</div>
    </div>
</div>

</br>

<div class="clickMe">ClickMe</div>
```

Am I imagining it or is there a clear difference between saying:

```
<script>


    $('.content .clickMe').click(function () {

        alert('you clicked');

    }); 


</script>
```

Or saying:

```
<script>


    $('.content').find('.clickMe').click(function () {

        alert('you clicked');

    })


</script>
```

Is one of those methods preferable over the other and if so, what's the main difference?

Comment: There's no difference in the results. The first may be slightly faster since you're only calling one function instead of two.

Comment: In your code example the result would be equivalent and either is acceptable. jQuery gives you many ways to skin the same cat

Comment: @j08691 Is there a situation in which one method would not work over the other? I could svear that sometimes the  $('.content .clickMe') way seems to have failed while .find() worked. But I'm not sure what could cause that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308405/css-selectors-vs-jquery-traversal and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282458/when-to-use-jquerys-find